# JavaScript increment images

Tags: javascript, html, image, increment

I'm trying to use JavaScript to list images 01-40 in order automatically.

Like this:

```
<img src="01.jpg" />
<img src="02.jpg" />
<img src="03.jpg" />
<img src="04.jpg" />
<img src="05.jpg" />
...
```

I don't want to write each img src manually, as I want to use this on multiple pages

I'd like the image starting and ending number to be variables that I can edit easily.

Comment: Did you try something ? Do you know how to create a loop ?

Comment: Does the images get served through ajax ? Why dont you do this through the server (php or whatever) ?

Comment: I've tried a few things I've seen on here. And no, I know very little Javascript. I have to do this client-side, I am using Dropbox to host the images and HTML page.

Comment: should they appear in the order they are created or should they just be in the right order at the end?

Comment: I'd like them to appear in ascending order by name.

Comment: Looking through the answers I would think @bitoiu's answer should be accepted as its more reusable especially since the initial question indicated that this is to be used on multiple pages. Using a function is better than copying and pasting the code on multiple pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the parent element for imgs:

```
for ( var i = FIRST_NUMBER ; i < LAST_NUMBER ; i++ ) {
    var elem = document.createElement("img");
    if ( i < 10 ) {
        elem.setAttribute("src", "0"+i+".jpg");
    } else {    
        elem.setAttribute("src", i+".jpg");
    }
    document.getElementById(PARENT_ID).appendChild(elem);
}
```

Comment: This worked for what I wanted, just one more thing, the images that are < 10 begin with 0

How would I include this into the automation?

Comment: after var elem = document.createElement("img"); add this : if (i<10) elem.setAttribute("src", "0"+i+".jpg"); else elem.setAttribute("src", i+".jpg");

Comment: I updated the code to use your convention "0" + i.
@Coder : good observation.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function img_create(startIndex, endIndex) {
    for (i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
        var oImg=document.createElement("img");
            oImg.setAttribute('src', i+".jpg");
            //other attributes you need
            document.body.appendChild(oImg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var to = 10;
var from = 0;
for (i = from; i < to; i++){
    var elem = new Element('img', { src: i + '.jpg' });
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

it will append to `<body>` images with names from 0.jpg to 9.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lw3bjcx4/1/

```
function createImages(count, elementId) {

    // Get the container element where you want to create the images
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId)

    // Loop count times over to create count image elements
    for (var i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {

        // Create a new image element
        var imageElement = document.createElement('img')

        // Set the source to index.jpg where index is 0,1,2,3.... count
        imageElement.setAttribute('src', i + ".jpg")

        // Append the new image element to the choosen container.
        element.appendChild(imageElement)
    }
}

// Test to create 10 images.
createImages(10,"imgs")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
var imgdiv = document.getElementById('imgdiv');
var img = imgdiv.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i=0;i<40;i++){
  img[i].src=i+'.jpg';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to all other answers, where you don't need to use an id to put images in. Just paste the script tag where you need to have the images. For example, if you put it in a div, the script will automatically insert the images in place.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var thisScriptNode = document.currentScript;

    for(var i = 1 ; i <= 40 ; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = ("00" + i).substr(-2) + ".jpg";
        thisScriptNode.parentNode.insertBefore(img, thisScriptNode);
    }
</script>
```

You can easily change the number of leading zeros. For example, to get numbers with three characters, replace `"00"` with `"000"` and `-2` with `-3`.